# How to get the id of google_pubsub_subscription_iam_member?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to import this resource to my Terraform state, but I cannot find the ID of it. Since it's not a traditional resource like a Pub/Sub topic or a Cloud Function I really don't know where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pubsub subscription IAM resources can be imported using the project id, subscription name, role, and member. You will need to specify all four for the `iam_member`.

```
terraform import google_pubsub_subscription_iam_member.<resource name> "projects/<project-id>/subscriptions/<subscription-name> roles/<role> <member>"
```